# Creates a trigger on SQL Server that updates an Access table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, linked-server

I have an Access table and a copy of that table in SQL Server.

Every time I modify a record in the SQL Server table I'd like to update his sister in Access.

To do that, I created a Linked Server in SQL. Then, I wrote a stored procedure that update the linked table (and that works). Then, I wrote a trigger that launches the stored procedure.

And when I try to update the table, I get the following exception:

> Error 7390: "The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server MSAccessConnect does not support the required transaction interface."

I tried to run the update query directly from the trigger (without the stored procedure) and I have the same issue.

Here the trigger's code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_essica_update
ON Ricette
AFTER UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
    DECLARE @ID INT,
            @Spessore FLOAT,
            @Essenza VARCHAR(50),
            @Temp_1 TINYINT,
            @Temp_2 TINYINT,
            @Temp_3 TINYINT,
            @Umid_1 SMALLINT,
            @SerrZona2 TINYINT,
            @SerrZona3 TINYINT,
            @Velocit FLOAT,
            @Ventole_Zona1 TINYINT,
            @Ventole_Zona2 TINYINT,
            @Ventole_raffr TINYINT;

    SELECT 
        @ID = ID,
        @Spessore = Spessore,
        @Essenza = Essenza,
        @Temp_1 = Temp_1,
        @Temp_2 = Temp_2,
        @Temp_3 = Temp_3,
        @Umid_1 = Umid_1,
        @SerrZona2 = SerrZona2,
        @SerrZona3 = SerrZona3,
        @Velocit = Velocit,
        @Ventole_Zona1 = Ventole_Zona1,
        @Ventole_Zona2 = Ventole_Zona2,
        @Ventole_raffr = Ventole_raffr 
    FROM 
        INSERTED;

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    EXEC sp_update_access 
            @ID, @Spessore, @Essenza,
            @Temp_1, @Temp_2, @Temp_3,
            @Umid_1, @SerrZona2, @SerrZona3,
            @Velocit, @Ventole_Zona1, @Ventole_Zona2,
            @Ventole_raffr;
GO
```

I would like to Update the access table as exactly I do with the SQL one.
As a sort of synchronization between two tables.

Thank you very much.

Comment: On top of the fact that you can't update a linked server through a transaction inside a trigger, as the error message has already told you, your trigger is written as if any update can only ever possibly affect one row. What if an update affects two rows, or 12 rows, or all rows? What values do you think you get in all those scalar variables?

Comment: Why are you keeping two copies of the same data anyway? Just store the data in sql server and drop the table in Access. Change your Access code to always pull data from the sql server table. Then your whole issue resolves itself and you have made a first step in improving your data handling.

Comment: Ok Aaron, how I can update only a row at a time?

Comment: The point that Aaron is making is that your trigger MUST allow for multiple row updates.

Comment: I have a very old program tha have some settings stored locally in tha access file. I would like to store and eventually change these settings from SQL Server.

Comment: Sean, there is a way to do that?

Comment: Yes but nothing that you can magically click a button and your logic becomes set based. You would either need a cursor/loop to go through the rows in inserted row by agonizing row, or change your stored procedure to receive a table valued parameter. Also, FWIW you might want to consider a different prefix, or even better no prefix at all for your stored procedure name. The sp_ prefix is not a great idea. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Thank you Sean, I will try some of your suggestions in the coming days.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: How quickly does MS Access need to be updated? If this is a small table (i.e. under 10000 rows), you're better off just running a scheduled job that refreshes the MS Access table every ten minutes or so. Trigger's are to be avoided. Triggers that do anything beyond working on tables in the same SQL Server shouldn't be used at all because there's too much that can go wrong

Comment: Nick, the MS Access table can be updated even one month at a time. I just want use triggers only to automate the job.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now I tried to change my trigger. I added a cursor to iterate the inserted table and I removed the stored procedure.

But it still raise the same error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_essica_update
ON Ricette
AFTER UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
    DECLARE @IC INT,
            @Spessore float,
            @Essenza varchar(50),
            @Temp_1 tinyint,
            @Temp_2 tinyint,
            @Temp_3 tinyint,
            @Umid_1 smallint,
            @SerrZona2 tinyint,
            @SerrZona3 tinyint,
            @Velocit float,
            @Ventole_Zona1 tinyint,
            @Ventole_Zona2 tinyint,
            @Ventole_raffr tinyint;
```

`DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM INSERTED;
OPEN cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @IC
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT
    @Spessore = Spessore,
    @Essenza = Essenza,
    @Temp_1 = Temp_1,
    @Temp_2 = Temp_2,
    @Temp_3 = Temp_3,
    @Umid_1 = Umid_1,
    @SerrZona2 = SerrZona2,
    @SerrZona3 = SerrZona3,
    @Velocit = Velocit,
    @Ventole_Zona1 = Ventole_Zona1,
    @Ventole_Zona2 = Ventole_Zona2,
    @Ventole_raffr = Ventole_raffr 
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE ID = @IC;

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE ac SET
        ac.Spessore = @Spessore,
        ac.Essenza = @Essenza,
        ac.Temp_1 = @Temp_1,
        ac.Temp_2 = @Temp_2,
        ac.Temp_3 = @Temp_3,
        ac.Umid_1 = @Umid_1,
        ac.SerrZona2 = @SerrZona2,
        ac.SerrZona3 = @SerrZona3,
        ac.[Velocità] = @Velocit,
        ac.Ventole_Zona1 = @Ventole_Zona1,
        ac.Ventole_Zona2 = @Ventole_Zona2,
        ac.Ventole_raffr = @Ventole_raffr
    FROM OPENQUERY(MSAccessConnectTestTrigger,'SELECT * FROM Ricette') AS ac
    WHERE ID = @IC
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @IC

END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur`

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron said, first loop the new updating records through cursor and then call your stored procedure to made the changes in target table using linked server. Please find the sample code.

Alter trigger tr_update_dim_bus on dim_bus
  after update 
  as 
  begin
  declare @bus_no varchar(20)
  --select @bus_no=bus_no from inserted
  declare db_cursor cursor for select bus_no from inserted
  open db_cursor
  fetch next from db_cursor into @bus_no
  while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
  begin

exec sp_update_dim_bus @bus_no=@bus_no -- call your sp
  fetch next from db_cursor into @bus_no

end
  close db_cursor
  deallocate db_cursor
  end